# Move constructor and non-const copy constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-c++-2012

I am new in move constructor, I surveyed from some sites and tried using the Visual Studio 11 Express Beta..

Below is my testing code...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
      : Memory(nullptr)
    {
        cout<<"Foo Constructor"<<endl;
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        cout<<"~Foo Destructor"<<endl;
        if(Memory != nullptr)
            delete []Memory;
    }
    Foo(Foo& rhs)
      : Memory(nullptr)
    {
        cout<<"Copy Constructor"<<endl;

        //allocate
        //this->Memory = new ....
        //copy 
        //memcpy(this->Memory, rhs.Memory...);
    }

    Foo& operator=(Foo& rhs)
    {
        cout<<"="<<endl;
    }
    void* Memory;

    Foo(int nBytes) { Memory = new char[nBytes]; }

    Foo(Foo&& rhs)
    {
        cout<<"Foo Move Constructor"<<endl;
        Memory = rhs.Memory;
        rhs.Memory = nullptr;
    }
};

Foo Get()
{
    Foo f;
    return f; 
    //return Foo();
}
void Set(Foo rhs)
{
    Foo obj(rhs);
}
int main()
{
    Set(Get());
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why it will not enter move constructor.

It's really a Rvalue from Get();

If I modified non-const copy constructor from const constructor,

it will enter move constructor. Behavior changed...

Could anyone kindly explain why it happened?

Comment: `delete [] void_ptr;` is undefined behaviour. Note that `delete nullptr` is perfectly fine, no need to check beforehand. Also, no need for all the useless boilerplate code. Cut that, and paste a clean example into the question. Read http://sscce.org.

Comment: Oh, and the answer to the question: You were most likely [outsmarted by the compiler](http://ideone.com/wZEKF) (note the missing construction copy inside `g`, this is what your example actually prints). With optimizations enabled, the compiler simply elides all those moves/copies.

Comment: @Xeo: Your example is missing a `return` in `X f()`.

Comment: @Mankarse: Ehh.. yes, thanks. Not anymore, now. And the point still stands (this was just a "typo").

Comment: @Xeo: Just thought I'd point it out before your 5 minute edit window ran out.

Comment: I can't see any code. Please post a complete question with any example code in the body of your question.

Comment: Hi Xeo, if I use X(X &){ std::cout << "copy ctor\n"; }...why the result differed.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo():
        Memory(nullptr)
    {
        cout<< this << "Foo Constructor"<<endl;
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        cout<< this << "~Foo Destructor"<<endl;
        if(Memory != nullptr)
            delete []Memory;
    }

    Foo(Foo& rhs)
        :Memory(nullptr)
    {
        cout<<this << "Copy Constructor"<<endl;

        //allocate
        //this->Memory = new ....
        //copy 
        //memcpy(this->Memory, rhs.Memory...);
    }

    Foo& operator=(Foo& rhs)
    {
        cout<<"="<<endl;
    }
    void* Memory;

    Foo(int nBytes) { Memory = new char[nBytes]; }

    Foo(Foo&& rhs)
        {
        cout<<this << "Foo Move Constructor"<<endl;

                 Memory = rhs.Memory;


                 rhs.Memory = nullptr;
        }

};

Foo Get()
{
    Foo f;
    cout << &f << "f" <<endl;
    return f; 
}

void Set(Foo rhs)
{
    Foo obj(rhs);
    cout << &obj << "obj"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    Set(Get());
    return 0;
}
```

output...

```
0x7fffe38fa0a0 Foo Constructor
0x7fffe38fa0a0 f
0x7fffe38fa070 Copy Constructor
0x7fffe38fa070 obj
0x7fffe38fa070 ~Foo Destructor
0x7fffe38fa0a0 ~Foo Destructor
```

**Answer:** Due to the **Named Return Value Optimization** the parameter rhs is constructed inplace as an alias of local variable f. (That is to say rhs and f are the same instance).

As rhs is an lvalue, the copy constructor is used to copy construct obj from rhs.